# php/mysql checkbox on vs. True vs. 1

Tags: php, sql, checkbox

this should not be hard but I'm struggling with it so I thought I'd request help as I could not finding anything specific on web.

I am posting from a checkbox on a form.  When I look at the querystring in browser window when I freeze output, it shows, the names of the variables = on.  Similarly, when I echo the posted values they show up as on.  The problem is when inserting into the dbase although inputting TRUE works, on does not. Fieldtype is tinyint(1).  Do I have to convert all the ons to TRUEs.  I feel like this has never been a problem before.

```
<form action="processform.php" method="post">
<input type = "checkbox" name="var1" CHECKED>
<input type = "checkbox" name="var2" CHECKED>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></form>
```

script on other end.

```
$var1 = $_POST['var1'];
$var2 = $_POST['var2'];
echo $var1; //echoes "on"

$sql = "INSERT into table (var1,var2) VALUES (TRUE,TRUE)"; //works
$sql = "INSERT into table (var1,var2) VALUES ($var1,$var2)"; //does not work.
$sql = "INSERT into table (var1,var2) VALUES ('$var1','$var2')"; //does not work.

mysql_query($sql);
```

Is this a typo?  Can't imagine you really need to change "on" blank to TRUE or FALSE for each variable

Comment: why do you think trying to insert a string in to an int field type is a good idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include a `value=""` field if you want to return a value other then ON

```
<input type = "checkbox" name="var2" value="1" CHECKED>
```

Comment: Just changing the HTML still leaves the possibility of SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `value="TRUE"` to each checkbox in your HTML.

Or, your assignments to `$var1` and `$var2` could set them to `TRUE`/`FALSE` or `1`/`0` depending on whether `$_POST['var1']` and `$_POST['var2']` are set or not.  My recollection of checkboxes in HTML is that they're present in `$_POST[]` if set, and absent if not set.

```
$var1 = isset($_POST['var1']);
$var2 = isset($_POST['var2']);
```

I hope that you aren't actually using the code in your question, that's a fine opening for a SQL-injection attack.

Comment: Yeah the key/value won't be there if it's not checked.

Comment: In that case, he can just use `isset()`.  Thanks for the confirmation @appclay.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Consider changing it to something like this and you'll be able to avoid SQL injection and what you're trying to do should work:

```
$var1 = isset($_POST['var1']) ? 1 : 0;
$var2 = isset($_POST['var2']) ? 1 : 0;
echo $var1; //echoes "on"

$sql = "INSERT into table (var1,var2) VALUES (TRUE,TRUE)"; //works
$sql = "INSERT into table (var1,var2) VALUES ($var1,$var2)"; //should work.
$sql = "INSERT into table (var1,var2) VALUES ('$var1','$var2')"; //should also work.

mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: It should be possible to just use `isset` -- since it's a checkbox it's either set and he doesn't care about the value (1) or it's not set (0).  It could be as simple as `$var1 = isset($_POST['var1']);`.

Answer (score 0):

TRUE boolean evaluates  to 1, = int
The other 2 are strings either "on" of the actual text $var1, but the field type is int, so that makes no sense

you could just set the input value to 1 and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

The field is a tinyint(1).  You can't put the string "on" into an integer field!

So you can use TRUE/FALSE or 1/0.

It wouldn't be much work to write a small function that returns TRUE or 1 if the value passed in is "on" and returns FALSE or 0 otherwise... something like

```
function ConvertCheckboxValue($value) {
    return $value == "on" ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: Regarding on being a string, it's not an ordinary string as it's produced by the checkbox.  In that sense, my recollection is that it's similar to TRUE which is also not a string and can go into Tinyint.  I believe on is a boolean though I may be wrong. I have another script that is identical that updates from a checkbox into a tinyint field fine.  Maybe it's because this is an insert as opposed to an update....  However, I will try including the value 1.  Regarding the injection attack, this is just a prototype... All the form data will get sanitized through a function before production.

Comment: When I set value=1, interestingly, it passes "on" giving the same problem as before.  When I set value="TRUE" it passes TRUE.  On the other end, I have to take TRUE out of ticks for the insert statement to work.  However, I don't feel good about this resolution as using on with ticks is working for me in another script.  The inconsistency doesn't seem right.  Perhaps I should post that.

Comment: 'TRUE' in tick marks and TRUE without them work.  1 works but '1' in tick marks doesn't.  I guess I will just use TRUE.  I will just move on for now but this does seem idiosyncratic.  Thanks to everyone for answers.

Answer (score 0):

TRUE works because PHP isn't strongly typed, and anything "truthy" converts into a string of "1", which is happening as you build up that sql statement.  The easiest solution is to make the value attribute of your input = "1".  When you pull it out of the $_GET array it will be a string "1", which will work in your tinyint field in the database.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="var2" value="1" />
```

You'll definitely want to preprocess it to avoid sql injection like other's have mentioned

```
$var2 = $_GET['var2'] === '1' ? '1' : '0';
```

I'd specifically set the $var2 to a string of '1' or '0' so it's clearer that you are actually expecting those values for your tinyint field.

Comment: Actually, the `TRUE` in his example was in the SQL statement, and not processed by PHP.  MySQL is going to treat the boolean literals `TRUE` as 1 and `FALSE` as 0.

Comment: have placed it in answer below.  Thx!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
var myVal = ( $('#myCheckbox').is(':checked') ) ? 1 : 0;

alert('myVal is: ' +myVal); //alerts 1 if checked, 0 if not checked
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tjyntj1b/)</kbd>